# SPO 2013 - How to export user profiles into an Excel sheet?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, user-profile, export, printing

We have O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

We are using people search center as our intranet "Phone Book"/Staff Directory. Few of our employees asked if it could be possible to print out all the users and their information.

Can this be done? Is it possible to print users and their information straight from the search results or can they be exported into a Sharepoint list and from there to an Excel sheet for printing? Or maybe some other way?

**EDIT:** I don't have any experience in working with Rest APIs or CSOM. Also my goal is that the end-users could somehow easily export and/or print out the current users and their information.

I'm eternally grateful for solutions regarding this matter! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with a code based solution, use the Client side object model to connect to your tenant's user profile service and export the data. [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Profile/geetanjali%20arora/activity) is a good post to do it. You will have to loop through all the user profiles and export the data.

You can also make use of the people search data. Query the people search using the rest API to get all the crawled user profile data and export it into an excel sheet. Refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109836/people-search-using-csom-api)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't done anything with Client side object models or rest APIs so could you elaborate a little bit? How should I get started to use either of those methods you linked? Also these both methods seem to be so hard that the end-users cannot do it themselves whenever they need to.. are there any easier/"automatic" solutions? :)

Comment: Well if you extract the file and upload it to a shared location(periodically ?) within a sharepoint site, the users can use that file. However if you want the users to generate the file on-the-fly, i believe there is no way you can do it OOB (that is my understanding). You may have to write a SharePoint app to achieve this. Client object model helps us to interact with sharepoint sites through code which is running outside your SP server. This is precisely what you will be required to do if you write custom code for SharePoint online. Below are some references for you to get started (contd...)

Comment: [Client site object model](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/working-client-object-model-microsoft-sharepoint),[Apps in Sharepoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930(v=office.15).aspx), [Provider hosted app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381(v=office.15).aspx),

Comment: Thank you @Vipul Kelkar for your information! I will get started on those reference links and try to study things a bit.. I'll update the status of this question & answer if/when I manage to succeed using your directions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will be accepting Vipul Kelkar's answer as it is correct. I still managed to find an easier solution that is acceptable to us so I want to share it here as an extra answer.

Instructions on how to export user information into an excel sheet:

1. First we need to obtain LIST ID and VIEW ID from the user information list that can be found at Site Settings -> People and Groups
2. From the list of views, choose (click) the view you want to use in the exported information and you'll see the LIST ID and VIEW ID in the URL
3. Insert your site name, LIST ID and VIEW ID in this url and press enter: `https://sitename.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=[LISTID]&View=[VIEWID]&CacheControl=1`
4. When it asks what to do with the file, open it in Excel and put in your (intranet/o365) login credentials
5. Done!

OPTIONAL STEPS:

1. You can also make a shortcut to use the export URL straight from the computer desktop.
2. Right click on the desktop and make a new shortcut and paste that export URL in the path and that's it. When that shortcut is opened, it will trigger the export function.

I hope someone find this helpful. Also once more thanks to Vipul too! :-)

Source: http://www.andrewjbillings.com/exportinguserinfolist/

Comment: The user information list will only contain the users that have been granted access to the particular site. So it is not necessary you will get the details of the other users in the user profiles who are not in the site.If that is what you are looking for, you can follow that method :)   Also the list is hidden so you dont want the end users to directly access and export data. Refer [this](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list) and [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68586/how-is-the-user-information-list-populated)

Comment: You are right. I'm actually aware of all that and that's why I'm still thinking of using one of the methods you posted. Thank you for your answers. :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: For the new community site, the "members" aren't kept in the security group  called *sitename members*. Instead they are in a special list called Community Members. But the same technique works -- you just get the guids by editing the view and pulling them out of the URL. Awesome. Thanks Tenttu!